# How to cite laws and regulations completely inline?

Tags: biblatex, citing, legal-style

[As it has been covered before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53589/98645), I'd [like to cite laws/regulations/directives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76248/how-to-implement-a-jurisdiction-biblatex-entry-type) or e.g. court decisions.

### Use case

My jurisdiction is Germany, in case that matters for the style.
I don't write a huge paper or so, it's rather just appeals to statements of case/complaints/note of submissions or so.
In my particular case I want to [improve my LaTeX template for](https://github.com/rugk/ifg-letter-appeal) writing appeals to official notices to “freedom of information” (FOI) requests (in German: Informationsfreiheitsgesetz, IFG).
Usually, there is no bibliography at the end, but everything is named inline (also no footnotes or so).
If a citation is used again, it may [use terms like ibit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554351/98645) [or so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558160/98645), which I already know how to do though, however (see linked questions).

### Tried solutions

So I've tried everything that was recommend in the posts before. The package `biblatex-german-legal` did not work.
`biblatex-juradiss` is quite okay and nice from how to define things.

I now e.g. have this legal commentary:

```
@commentary{djvIfgKommentierung,
    author = {Dr.~Wilhelm Mecklenburg Mecklenburg and Benno H. Pöppelmann},
    title = {Informationsfreiheitsgesetz},
    subtitle = {Gesetztexte, Kommentierungen, Fallbeispiele Erläuterungen},
    titleaddon = {Information – Ihr gutes Recht},
    date = {2007-02},
    editor = {{Deutscher Journalisten-Verband e.~V.}},
    editora = {{Vereinigte Dienstleistungsgewerkschaft (ver.di)}},
    editorb = {{Humanistische Union}},
    editorc = {{netzwerk recherche}},
    editord = {{Transparency International – Deutsches Chapter}},
    language = {ngerman},
    origlanguage = {ngerman},
    publisher = {DJV},
    DISlocation = {Berlin},
    isbn = {978-3-935819-22-0},
    pagetotal = {223},
    DISurl = {https://netzwerkrecherche.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ifg-kommentar-buch.pdf}
}
```

Now here is e.g. one sentence how I'd like it to look like:

> Generell gilt, dass „in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung […] die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und –darzulegen“ [Mecklenburg, W. & Pöppelmann, B. (2007). Informationsfreiheitsgesetz. Berlin: DJV.] ist, „warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche [nachteilige] Auswirkungen [nach § 3 IFG Nr. 1] eintreten“[ebd.].

The same as a screenshot:
[image: see text above]

(It does not have to be exactly the same, but basically list all information.)
Generally, I just want it to display a good full citation in there, **with all fields that make sense** for such legal documents.

source code:

```latex
            Generell gilt, dass
            \enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen}\cite{djvIfgKommentierung} ist,
            \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}\cite{djvIfgKommentierung}.
```

This example code uses the `csquotes` package.
With all current solutions, I can only get it to use footnotes or endnotes/a bibliography to list all these information. However, for legal documents and things like that, this is rather rare, as far as I see.

For reference relevant preamble snippet:

```
\usepackage[style=biblatex-juradiss,
sortcites=true,
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
%maxcitenames=3,
minbibnames=3, % cite up to three authors in bib
backref=true,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

### MWE

Here a full minimum workable example with the hardcoded (wanted) design and the new code that does not work yet:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-juradiss,
sortcites=true,
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
%maxcitenames=3,
minbibnames=3, % cite up to three authors in bib
backref=true,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

% deutsch
\usepackage[
english,
ngerman,
% shorthands=off
]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@commentary{djvIfgKommentierung,
    author = {Dr.~Wilhelm Mecklenburg Mecklenburg and Benno H. Pöppelmann},
    title = {Informationsfreiheitsgesetz},
    subtitle = {Gesetztexte, Kommentierungen, Fallbeispiele Erläuterungen},
    titleaddon = {Information – Ihr gutes Recht},
    date = {2007-02},
    editor = {{Deutscher Journalisten-Verband e.~V.}},
    editora = {{Vereinigte Dienstleistungsgewerkschaft (ver.di)}},
    editorb = {{Humanistische Union}},
    editorc = {{netzwerk recherche}},
    editord = {{Transparency International – Deutsches Chapter}},
    language = {ngerman},
    origlanguage = {ngerman},
    publisher = {DJV},
    DISlocation = {Berlin},
    isbn = {978-3-935819-22-0},
    pagetotal = {223},
    DISurl = {https://netzwerkrecherche.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ifg-kommentar-buch.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Wanted (hardcoded)}
            Generell gilt, dass
            \enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen} [Mecklenburg, W. \& Pöppelmann, B. (2007). Informationsfreiheitsgesetz. Berlin: DJV.] ist,
            \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}[ebd.].

\section{Test}
            Generell gilt, dass
            \enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen}\cite{djvIfgKommentierung} ist,
            \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}\cite{djvIfgKommentierung}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a clear MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 AND https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407) plus maybe a screenshot of the current and the intended output. At the moment, there is a lot of effort involved just to create a document that recreates the question.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Done, added.

Comment: In addition, it is a common rule that you post your examples in English unless the problem is language-specific. In your case, the problem does not seem to be language-specific.

Comment: It's indeed somewhat language-specific, because the citation styles may be different. And also my used [`biblatex-juradiss` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-juradiss?lang=de) is a German package: “BibLaTeX stylefiles for German law theses”.

Comment: It's just a heads-up. If you use German sentences then it makes it more difficult for others to work with your code.

Comment: Okay thanks. It was just the best, real-life example I could use that demonstrates the whole lot of complex fields that may be added there.
I'm sorry if that is problematic to someone. Then please just ignore the sentences, the citation I want is in the brackets, i.e. beginning with `[Mecklenburg` and ending with `DJV.]`.

Comment: Another note: No I cannot use another document class, I use [`scrartcl` with `scrletter`](https://github.com/rugk/ifg-letter-appeal/blob/395c02b1d0f597d253ce7ec142b26df417f4b637/ifg-letter-appeal.tex#L6-L17) to properly generate letters, and the things needs to be letter, so I cannot just replace that.

Comment: I would definitely use footnotes. Stumbling over full-length in-text citations does not really help the flow of your text which, by its very nature, will be cumbersome enough to begin with. (Disclaimer: Most of my writing is legal, too.)

Comment: @Ingmar Maybe yeah, but did you look at all these (German) verdicts and stuff? They all write it inline, I've never really seen one to write it as footnotes. I mean, small quotes for laws may be okay, but even long commentaries or other verdicts were quoted inline.

Comment: I’d say it depends. Books, articles in journals, theses etc. certainly use footnotes in my jurisdiction (Austria), while verdicts do often use inline citations, but at least tend to keep it short and put it at the very end of a sentence. If forced, I’d probably would have used `Mecklenburg/Pöppelmann, Informationsfreiheitsgesetz (2007)`. Well, so much for my € 0.02 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use biblatex-juradiss as base I think it's the simplest to adjust the cite macro. To avoid interactions I'd define a new one.

[Edit: add loccit support & example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-juradiss,
sortcites=true,
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
minbibnames=3, % cite up to three authors in bib
backref=true,
giveninits=true,
loccittracker=constrict,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

% deutsch
\usepackage[
english,
ngerman,
% shorthands=off
]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @commentary{djvIfgKommentierung,
        author = {Dr.~Wilhelm Mecklenburg Mecklenburg and Benno H. Pöppelmann},
        title = {Informationsfreiheitsgesetz},
        subtitle = {Gesetztexte, Kommentierungen, Fallbeispiele Erläuterungen},
        titleaddon = {Information – Ihr gutes Recht},
        date = {2007-02},
        editor = {{Deutscher Journalisten-Verband e.~V.}},
        editora = {{Vereinigte Dienstleistungsgewerkschaft (ver.di)}},
        editorb = {{Humanistische Union}},
        editorc = {{netzwerk recherche}},
        editord = {{Transparency International – Deutsches Chapter}},
        language = {ngerman},
        origlanguage = {ngerman},
        publisher = {DJV},
        location = {Berlin},%modified to use the real location field
        isbn = {978-3-935819-22-0},
        pagetotal = {223},
        DISurl = {https://netzwerkrecherche.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ifg-kommentar-buch.pdf}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareLabeldate{%
    \field{date}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventdate}
    \field{origdate}
    \field{urldate}
    \literal{nodate}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldateparts}

%wrapper for the ibid citing
\DeclareCiteCommand{\legalcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{%
    \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
    {%
        \ifloccit{%
            \global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:ibid}%
        }{%
            \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:loccit}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:legal}\usebibmacro{cite:save}}%
}{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}


%cite format
\newbibmacro*{cite:legal}{%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {%
        \ifnameundef{labelname} {} {%
            \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
        }
        \iffieldundef{labelyear} {} {
            \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
            \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}\printdelim{yeartitledelim}}
        \usebibmacro{cite:label}
        \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}
        \usebibmacro{cite:location+publisher}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
}

%helper macros, this one is the definition of authoryear.cbx
\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
    \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}


\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:location+publisher}{%
    \iflistundef{location}{}{
        \printlist{location}%
        \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
    }%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit{\addperiod}%
    \newunit
}

%add loccite support, adopted from biblatex authortitle-ibid.cbx
\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifbool{cbx:loccit}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:loccit}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{loccit}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%to be changed after language setup
    \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\addspace}
}

%In case you also want to get ibid, with empty postnote but that's overriding the test
%\makeatletter
%\def\blx@loccit@numcheck#1{%
%   \blx@imc@iffieldundef{postnote}%
%   {%
%       \ifcsundef{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}%
%           {\@firstoftwo}%
%           {\@secondoftwo}%
%   }%
%   {%
%       \expandafter\blx@imc@ifpages%
%       \expandafter{\abx@field@postnote}%
%       {\blx@imc@iffieldequalcs{postnote}{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}}%
%       {\@secondoftwo}}}%
%\ExplSyntaxOff
%\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \section{Wanted (hardcoded)}
    Generell gilt, dass
    \enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen} [Mecklenburg, W. \& Pöppelmann, B. (2007). Informationsfreiheitsgesetz. Berlin: DJV.] ist,
    \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}[ebd.].
    
    
    \begin{refsection}
        \section{own cite macro Test}
        Generell gilt, dass
        \enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen}\legalcite{djvIfgKommentierung} ist,
        \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}\legalcite{djvIfgKommentierung}.
    \end{refsection}
    
    
    \begin{refsection}
        \legalcite[3]{djvIfgKommentierung} 
        
        \legalcite[3]{djvIfgKommentierung}
        
        \legalcite[4]{djvIfgKommentierung}
        
        \legalcite{djvIfgKommentierung} 
        
        \legalcite{djvIfgKommentierung} 
        
        
        \legalcite[2]{djvIfgKommentierung} 
        
        
    \end{refsection}
    
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

The name format is not setup correctly in you bibfile, so you might want to adjust this, but generally this is doing what you are expecting and compatible to the setup of biblatex-juradiss.

Comment: Nice, but does it also support [loco citato](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558160/98645)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had a really busy week. Not in the form before, I will add that in the example above.. You might want to change the value of the loccittracker option, Have a look at the biblatex documentation to choose the best value for your usecase.

Comment: The loco citato usage is wrong though. See https://github.com/rugk/ifg-letter-appeal/pull/7/commits/ba93b5f9fa06e16c690c0ac205a08dd7573dcdfa

Also tested your example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/djmbnmjtmjwj

`loccit` should be cited if the page is different, and `ibid` only if everything equals.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missunderstoof that one. But it's easily fixed. But it seems like you also want to get ibid if both cites had empty postnotes?! I change the example above and include a comment in case you want this, because the default behaviour would set the loccittracker to false if the postnote is empty.

Comment: Correct, AFAIK the proper behaviour would be to get `ibid` for empty refs.

Comment: It still adds mysterious spaces at the start of the short ref, e.g. `[ a. a. O.]`.

Answer (score 2):

People might be interested in [What is best practice re. handling legal sources with Biblatex/Biber for disciplines other than law?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437824/35864).

There are some `biblatex` styles for German legal citations ([`biblatex-jura` [abandoned, last update 2008]](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-jura), [`biblatex-juradiss` [based on `biblate-dw`, sometimes gets emergency bugfixes by Herbert Voß, but not actively developed]](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-juradiss), [`biblatex-jura2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-jura2) and [`biblatex-german-legal`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-german-legal)), but none of them seems to have the `verbose`-like setup with full first citations and shorter subsequent citations that you describe.

Something like the behaviour you described can be coded together with standard (or `biblatex-ext`'s) `verbose-ibid` style. Depending on whether or not you want to be able to have a longer bibliography entry at the end with more data and depending on what output you'd like to see for other entry types, more work is needed.

Note that the standard styles don't have anything special prepared for court decisions, law commentaries etc., so you have to experiment with other entry type or roll your own driver for those types.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
english,
ngerman,
% shorthands=off
]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,
  autocite=plain,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given:inits}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given:inits}%
       \clearfield{subtitle}%
       \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
       \clearfield{booksubtitle}%
       \clearfield{pagetotal}%
       \clearfield{isbn}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{djvIfgKommentierung,
  author      = {Wilhelm Mecklenburg and Benno H. Pöppelmann},
  title       = {Informationsfreiheitsgesetz},
  subtitle    = {Gesetztexte, Kommentierungen, Fallbeispiele Erläuterungen},
  date        = {2007-02},
  publisher   = {Deutscher Journalisten-Verband e.~V.
                 and Vereinigte Dienstleistungsgewerkschaft (ver.di)
                 and Humanistische Union
                 and netzwerk recherche
                 and Transparency International – Deutsches Chapter},
  language    = {german},
  publisher   = {DJV},
  location    = {Berlin},
  isbn        = {978-3-935819-22-0},
  pagetotal   = {223},
  DISurl      = {https://netzwerkrecherche.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ifg-kommentar-buch.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Wanted (hardcoded)}
Generell gilt, dass
\enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{}
die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret  benennen und \textendash darzulegen}
[Mecklenburg, W. \& Pöppelmann, B. (2007). Informationsfreiheitsgesetz. Berlin: DJV.] ist,
\enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige} Auswirkungen
\textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten} [ebd.].

\section{Test}
Generell gilt, dass
\enquote{in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung \textelp{} 
die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und \textendash darzulegen}
\autocite{djvIfgKommentierung}
ist, \enquote{warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche \textins{nachteilige}
Auswirkungen \textins{nach §\,3 IFG Nr.~1} eintreten}
\autocite{djvIfgKommentierung}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Generell gilt, dass "in der Begründung einer ablehnenden Entscheidung [...] die nachteiligen Auswirkungen konkret zu benennen und –darzulegen" [Mecklenburg, W. & Pöppelmann, B. H. Informationsfreiheitsgesetz. Berlin: DJV, Feb. 2007] ist, "warum die Möglichkeit besteht, dass solche [nachteilige] Auswirkungen [nach §3 IFG Nr. 1] eintreten" [ebd.].]

Comment: Thanks. "Note that the standard styles don't have anything special prepared for court decisions, law commentaries etc." So we have solved one problem now, but (as I cannot use `biblatex-juradiss` as before or so), we have (re)introduced another (previously fixed) issue… hmm? Does not sound too good, does it?

Comment: Also note I have code for doing that ibid etc. stuff, at least with the `numeric-comp` style,see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558167/98645. I wonder whether that could be adapted here? (I hope it's not too style-dependent.)

Comment: @rugk Question is if you actually need all that fancy stuff or if you can make do with the standard entry types. For example, you used `@commentary` in your MWE, but the example works just as well with `@book` (in fact the way commentaries are usually cited in some law citation styles really made me think whether `@commentary` is the best solution here given what you appear to want as output). ...

Comment: ... If you do want to cite court decisions and are not happy with the standard output, you can always look into taking the driver definitions from one of the law styles that are on CTAN. If that's to complicated and you just want a one-off with full control, you can try 'freeform' citations (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438759/35864). ...

Comment: ... As for your *op cit.* features. They are in principle also applicable here, but the exact code needs to be slightly different here than in `numeric-comp`. But it only makes sense to think about how exactly you want to do that once you know how you implement the base style. ...

Comment: ... I realise you are not asking for my advice, but my two cents are that too many Latin abbreviations just come across as obnoxious: Sticking with "ebd."/"ibid." for space reasons is perfectly legitimate, but I wouldn't overdo it. And I wouldn't invent/use complex rules for whether or not the postnote is shown: Show it for all citations, "ibid." or not, and do your readers the favour of being able to find the pinpoint reference quickly.